# Centre plot inside a node (Sigmoid Neural Node)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Essentially I want to make a graph topology of a neural network. Since I have different type of nodes (rbf, sigmoid, linear) I want them to have in the node a shape of the function, something almost everyone have seen. But for some reason the plots are always going upper than the node boundary and could not find how to fix it.

The code is:

```
\tikzstyle{probState}=[ circle,
                    thick,
                    minimum size=45pt,
                    draw=blue!50,
                    fill=white,
                    line width=2.5pt,
                    font=\large]
\node [probState] (test){
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right, baseline]
        \begin{axis}[axis lines=none,width=80pt,height=80pt,
         ylabel shift=-0.1cm]
        \addplot[color=red]{1/(1+exp(-x))-2};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };
```

The result is (ignore the line and theta they are just from another graph):

[image: Result]

How can I centre the plot in the node?

Comment: get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wpvDy.png. with `pgfplots` v1.11. May be you should update `pgfplots`.

Comment: @Belov: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: I'm using sharelatex. Was hoping it would be there up to date :/

Comment: I found my problem, since for the other nodes I had [text height=1.5ex] as from the example that shifted the plot also. Thanks a lot, pointing out that it worked for someone else made it clear where to search for the problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem which resulted from code not included in the question. [See comments.]

Comment: Just had the same problem: solved by including `axis` environment inside the node, i.e. \node (mynode) at (1, 2) { \begin{axis}...\end{axis} };